# Fastest way to query a large dataset within Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm

I'm about to port an iOS app to Android. The app uses an SQLite database of 150MB supported by core data. Some heavy queries sometimes take up to 10 seconds. Therefore I'm searching for the perfect way of querying data within Android. Are there any good suggestions before I start?

Or any libraries I can use to make life easier, like ORM tools, GreenDAO, ORMLite?

Comment: Identify the costly queries and make sure you are optimizing your queries and have good indices on your tables. GreenDAO will save you some typing, but it won't make the DB faster.

Answer (score 1):

[`ORMLite`](http://ormlite.com/) and [`GreenDAO`](http://greendao-orm.com/) are both good libraries, but I don't know if they will fit your needs. They'll use reflection (at least [`ORMLite`](http://ormlite.com/) I think it does) and will probably make things a bit slower for you.

I do not exactly know how you will use your data, but a nice solution would be to use `Loaders`, more specific [`CursorLoaders`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to access your database. This will by default access your data in sequence, so not all the entries will be loaded by default.

Comment: Just to confirm that [`GreenDAO`](http://greendao-orm.com/) do not use reflection. Instead you create a generator project which will produce java source code for your DAOs and entities. See [`DAO Code Generation Project`](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/introduction/)